# Unable to create virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am unable to create virtual environment using both Python 2.x or Python 3.x. When I try create virtual environment I get error:

```
$ virtualenv my_env2                                                                                                                                                                                           [0:05:17] ⚡[..........]
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/user/my_env2/bin/python2
Not overwriting existing python script /home/user/my_env2/bin/python (you must use /home/user/my_env2/bin/python2)
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/lynx/my_env2/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 40, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name requests
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2375, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 724, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 922, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 817, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/user/my_env2/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

The same error occurs for Python 3.x. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have `pip` installed (and working)? (And as an aside, how did you install Python originally?)

Comment: Can you try to install via `python -m venv <venvName>` for (both Python 2 and 3) and include the result of that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to do this with Python3. Try this command:

```
sudo python3 -m <your virtual env name>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, make a directory of any name :

```
mkdir testing
```

2. Then, moved to this newly created directory named testing :

```
cd testing
```

3. When you type  following command in this directory:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

You got error like :

The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

```
apt install python3.8-venv
```

4. Type the following command but  before that keep an eye on the version of python you installed on the machine; in my case its python3.8

```
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
```

5. Now, we can create a virtual environment and store its tools in the "bhandari" folder .

```
python3 -m venv bhandari
```

Note: you can named this "bhandari" folder; anyname you like( Standard practice is to name it "env" ...)

6. Now to activate your virtual environment, from the directory of your folder, type the following command this will activate our virtual environment in the “bhandari” folder

```
source bhandari/bin/activate
```

7. If you have successfully activated your virtual environment, you should see the (bhandari) word indicating that we are working in a virtual environment.

After this, we can install anything that will be isolated from the rest of the system....